# MySql Join on multi table index

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem in a query MySqL, my query does not succeed (It loads without ever giving results).

The query :

```
SELECT 
    a.id
FROM
    baseOne.tableOne c
LEFT JOIN baseTwo.tableTwo b
    ON b.avis = c.avis
LEFT JOIN baseOne.tableThree a
    ON a.avis = b.avis_tav
```

I have index on :

```
avis (baseOne.tableOne)
avis (baseTwo.tableTwo)
avis_tav(baseTwo.tableTwo)
avis (baseOne.tableThree)
```

Each tables contain ~40,000 lines 
The three tables are independent of each other (no foreign key, and i can't change that)

Why this query don't work ?

Thank you

Comment: What error are you getting? Does the query run but not return the results you expect? Edit your question to add this information. Show your table schemas.

Comment: To find out why indexes not working you can use EXPLAIN in your query https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html. It shoes which indexes are used and which indexes could be used. Simple add word EXPLAIN at the beginning of the query like this "EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM ....."

Comment: I have edit my question.

The explain give :
1  SIMPLE  c index  NULL PRIMARY  22  NULL 38435  Using index
1  SIMPLE  b  ref  uniq_idx_avis_requete,avis,avis_2  uniq_idx_avis_requete  767  func  1  
1  SIMPLE  a  index  NULL PRIMARY  257  NULL 67492  Using index

Comment: With out schemas is complicated, but try using FULL OUTER JOIN instead LEFT JOIN, maybe the result set of the first left join doesn't have any result.

Comment: Full Outer Join is not possible in MySQL. You need to stimulate it using left and right join.

Comment: Can you give you table structure.

Comment: These are very large tables (50-100+ column), so I can not give the structure here. (I can't change these tables). But the columns where the joins are made are VARCHAR (20)